# MySQL Connector/ODBC 8.0.17 for Excel on a Mac does not install properly

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, mysql

I am trying to get Excel for Mac to connect to MySQL, and have tried to download the ODBC connector found at [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/), only to get an installation failure.  If anyone knows how to fix this, or how to otherwise connect the current Mac version of Excel to a MySQL database, I would very much appreciate the guidance.

Comment: You say you tried to download it. You don't say how you tried to install it, or what the error is. This information is probably necessary in order to tell what the problem is. Please EDIT the question to make it more clear and complete.

Comment: Please follow @music2myear 's suggestion to share more information with us. You can also refer to the official document [Installing Connector/ODBC on macOS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-installation-binary-osx.html) for help.

Comment: I was using the .dmg install file and the installation failure was not specified.  However, thanks to the link that @HerbGu sent, I was able to diagnose the problem -- needed to install the iODBC manager at [link] (http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/Downloads).